# How to display only the last post sent to the database? PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, phpmyadmin

so i'm using foreach loop to grab the data from my database in phpmyadmin to then display it in my indextest.php file, which has the following code:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mt-4">

        <h6>
        <span style="color: blue;">BREAKING NEWS</span>
        <span id="test" style="padding-left: 10px;"><?php echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($post['created_at'])); ?></span>
        </h6>
        <!-- HEADLINE -->
        <h1><strong><a href="/single_page_main.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a></strong></h1>
            
        </strong></h1></a>
        <!-- TEXT BODY -->
        <h4><?php echo $post['body']; ?></h4> <!--displays the full body -->
        <h4><?php echo html_entity_decode(substr($post['body'], 0, 150) . '...'); ?></h4> 

        <a href="/single_page_main.php">
        <div class="button_subs float-left mb-4">Read More</div></a>

        </div>

        <!-- IMAGE -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img src="<?php echo '/assets/images/' , $post['image']; ?>" style="width: 100%;">

    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem is that it grabs all the posts in the database however I would like to grab only the last post (the last row) sent to the database? Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use need this SQL query with `id DESC LIMIT 1`:-

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE t ORDER BY t.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks @KUMAR, where do I write this? Sorry i'm a php beginner..

Comment: in your select sql query from where you get this `$posts` array.